# C# Access SQL select

Tags: c#

The system say

> "Syntax error in UPDATE statement."

```
cmd.CommandText = "Update Player set money = money + 100 where player_account = '" + origingalForm.playerAC + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please help me !

Datatype: money (integer), player_account (string)

Comment: What value is `value`? What type is `money`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us if your column types with your values are perfectly matched or not but, `MONEY` is [reserved keyword](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) in MS Access. You should use it with square brackets like `[MONEY]`

I know `MONEY` and `money` *can* be different keywords based on the system's case sensitive options but not in access by default as far as I know.

As a best practice, change it to *non-reserved* word.

Also don't use string concatenations for your values. Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The statement it self seems to be correct, only the `value` parameter or `origingalForm.playerAC` parameter can cause the problem. Please use the ADO.Net parameter system, to be sure the parameter will be passed in the correct format. Further more you prevent sql injection. Please search for this keywords, they were explaned a lot...

Look at this msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/dw70f090(v=vs.100).aspx), it will give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your update syntax is correct, the problem is in your variables.
**Add a Breack Point in Visual Studio at the line of your** `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` **and check** `cmd.CommandText` **value**.
After doing that If you still didn't find out your mistake, then post the `cmd.CommandText` value here so I can check it for you.